# regexp with varying integer lengths

Tags: regex, matlab

I want split these strings from

```
CH1Avg
Ch2Avg
Ch3
Ch4Avg
Ch5
Ch6Avg
Chan7
Channel9
Ch010
Ch011Avg
Chann12Average
```

...up to...

```
Ch100AVG
```

I need to split them into their consituent parts

```
"Ch", ##, "Avg"
```

1st and 3rd components are of variable length and form. I want to split using the 2nd component which is an integer of vary length from 0 to 100. The integer may or may not be zero padded.

Any thoughts? I am trying to use `()` without much success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the string into the constituent parts, I suggest using named tokens for convenience:

```
strCell = {'CH1Avg'
'Ch2Avg'
'Ch3'
'Ch4Avg'
'Ch5'
'Ch6Avg'
'Chan7'
'Channel9'
'Ch010'
'Ch011Avg'
'Chann12Average'}

out = regexp(strCell,'(?<channelName>\D+)(?<channelNum>\d+)(?<channelType>\w*)','names')
out = [out{:}];

out(end)
ans = 
    channelName: 'Chann'
     channelNum: '12'
    channelType: 'Average'
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on `(\d+)`. The parentheses ensure that the number you're splitting on will also become part of the array.